# Filter dataset from multiple columns of another dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider this df 'A':

```
     name  index     pet
0   Alice      2     dog
1     Bob      5     cat
2   Chuck     12     cat
3   Daren      4    bird
4   Emily      9    bird
```

And then this df 'B':

```
    pet
0   dog
1   cat
2   dog
3  bird
4   cat
5   cat
6  bird
7   cat
8  bird
9  bird
...
```

If the value in column 'index' from 'A' and the value from column 'pet' match the actual index of dataset 'B' together with the value in column 'pet' from dataset B, then keep those values, and filter out all the rest.

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
    pet
2   dog
5   cat
9  bird
...
```

What is the most efficient way to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Data:

`dfA`:

```
{'name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Chuck', 'Daren', 'Emily'],
 'index': [2, 5, 12, 4, 9],
 'pet': ['dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'bird', 'bird']}
```

`dfB`:

```
{'pet': ['dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'cat', 'cat', 'bird', 'cat', 'bird', 'bird']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a merge.

```
import pandas as pd

dfa = pd.DataFrame({'name': {0: 'Alice', 1: 'Bob', 2: 'Chuck', 3: 'Daren', 4: 'Emily'},
 'index': {0: 2, 1: 5, 2: 12, 3: 4, 4: 9},
 'pet': {0: 'dog', 1: 'cat', 2: 'cat', 3: 'bird', 4: 'bird'}})

dfb = pd.DataFrame({'pet': {0: 'dog',
  1: 'cat',
  2: 'dog',
  3: 'bird',
  4: 'cat',
  5: 'cat',
  6: 'bird',
  7: 'cat',
  8: 'bird',
  9: 'bird'}})

dfm = pd.merge(dfa, dfb, left_on=['index', 'pet'], right_on=[dfb.index, 'pet'])
dfm = dfm[['index', 'pet']].set_index('index', drop=True)
```

Output:

```
    pet
index   
2   dog
5   cat
9   bird
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to `reindex` `dfB` with `dfA['index']` and evaluate where the "pet" values match:

```
tmp = dfB.reindex(dfA['index'])
out = tmp[tmp['pet'].eq(dfA.set_index('index')['pet'])].rename_axis([None])
```

Another option is `map` dfB.index to "pet" column in `dfA` and create a boolean mask that shows where the "pet" columns match; then filter `dfB`:

```
out = dfB[dfB.index.map(dfA.set_index('index')['pet']) == dfB['pet']]
```

Output:

```
    pet
2   dog
5   cat
9  bird
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `to_records()` with `isin()`

```
(df2.loc[pd.Series(df2.reset_index()
                   .to_records(index=False)
                   .tolist())
         .isin(df1[['index','pet']]
               .to_records(index=False)
               .tolist())])
```

Output:

```
    pet
2   dog
5   cat
9  bird
```